# How can I know the number of bad sectors on my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I know how to to check / repair my hard drive but I don't know a way how to see the number of bad sectors on my hard drive.

P.S. It looks like my hard drive will die soon :-(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to detect bad sectors in Linux: you can use the disk utility (gui), or you can use the [badblocks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/badblocks.8.html) command to check your hard disk for bad sectors:

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/{device}
```

That should answer the question but for anyone else interested in how to mark them it can be done with 2 simple commands...

You add the bad blocks to a file...

```
sudo badblocks /dev/sdb > {/dir/to/filename}
```

and then tell `fsck` to mark these as unusable with ...

```
sudo fsck -l {/dir/to/filename} /dev/{device}
```

Comment: It seems that `e2fsck` has a `-c` option which calls `badblocks` itself and takes care of the block size. One apparently has to be really careful that those match if you do it your way.

Comment: This use of `badblocks`+`fsck` to mark bad blocks could be dangerous. From `badblocks` man page: "Important note: If the output of badblocks is going to be fed to the e2fsck or mke2fs programs, it is important that the block size is properly specified, since the block numbers which are generated are very dependent on the block size in use by the filesystem. For this reason, _it is strongly recommended that users not run badblocks directly, but rather use the -c option of the e2fsck and mke2fs programs_." See @john-mehorter answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about this just yesterday. +1

Answer (score 8):

Use fsck.ext3 (e2fsck) for instance  and use the -cc option

```
-c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do a read-only scan of the device in  order  to  find  any  bad
          blocks.   If  any  bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block inode to prevent them from being allocated to a
          file or directory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan will  be  done  using  a  non-destructive
          read-write test.`
```

> fsck -cc /dev/sda1

Comment: I have read this several times the last years but I don't know what is a non-destructive test. It doesn't change anything in the disk? Is it informative only?

Comment: I assume that it will try to write in each block, but write the original data back again.