# Ubuntu installation is slow, why?

Tags: system-installation

I am currently installing Ubuntu 12.04.3. Everything was going fine until I came across this...

> Installing System

It is sssooooooo close to being finished! Like 1/6 of the way there! I just wanted to know if this is normal or if something is wrong. I'm installing it through a flash drive if that helps

Also,what will happen if I press the skip button that pops up when I click Installing System?

Comment: try to unplugged your Internet connection and turn off wifi during installing.

Answer (score 1):

do try not to install - updating while installing.  Just do installing without connecting to Internet.

I too had this, and when I tried installing for my friend at his home (without internet) it was just as fast as other installations.

try it and let us know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu installation is slow could be caused by a slow mirror, the bandwidth from your ISP is low or there are [bad sectors](https://askubuntu.com/q/104063/) on the computer's hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this-do you know how much ram your system has? If it has under 512MBs, than ubuntu installation will be very slow, and will be sluggish when running it.

Edit: disconnecting the internet may help, Ubuntu may install updates while installing which will take a long time as was stated below. Good luck mate!

Comment: I have 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: I have 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: it should install great then-just do as was stated above and disconnect from the web if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I found that after a few freezes, very slow install, a couple of resets, that the auto side-by-side didn't work well, but after a great deal of pain in the manual partition section working out how it works, how to create partition, and as much pain working out what partitions are required, it installed snappy!.
Andrew Robertson

Answer (score -1):

I cleaned the fan because I guess my computer was overheated and then the speed is normal. Have a try. I don't think the problem is on the memory size or processor, because Ubuntu installer first test pre-requirements before install it.