# Dual booted win7 with 13.10 and seemingly I have lost the whole hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, hard-drive

I seriously need help !
I followed the instructions, and started to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside win 7. In the middle of installation, there was an error saying some file can not be copied, after that just nothing happened for "a long time" , I think here I made the decisive mistake, and restarted my laptop in the middle of installation process.

after I turned on my laptop, in the boot options there was no HDD !! it was just DVD to boot from, I tried to reinstall 13.10 using my DVD, this time it did not ask me to install it "alongside windows 7", it said, there is no operating system on this computer, just install 13.10. I continued but again (this time maybe because of "loss of HDD") it gives error about not being able to copy files.

I am here thanks to "try ubuntu before installing it" !! in the air

Why these things happened ?
How can I recover my HDD ?
How can I make sure there is no way, but to replace my HDD ?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="2976d82f-f4c6-4eb3-ab63-bb4aa2fbeca4" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 13.10 i386" TYPE="iso9660" 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: post the output of `sudo blkid` command.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for your comment ,but I am using Ubuntu desktop for the first time, Can you tell me exactly how to do it ? Note : I am running ubuntu just by DVD without having it been installed.

Comment: press control+alt+t keys on your keyboard, it will open up the terminal.On that terminal, run the above mentioned command.Finally post the output in your question.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="2976d82f-f4c6-4eb3-ab63-bb4aa2fbeca4" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 13.10 i386" TYPE="iso9660" 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: How did you partition your hard drive (`/dev/sda`)?

Comment: check for badsectors on your disk.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Before installing 13.10, In widows 7 partitioning tool, I partitioned a 20GB unallocated drive, to install ubuntu on

Comment: @AvinashRaj Can I look for badsectors by using a particular software ?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/104063/how-can-i-know-the-number-of-bad-sectors-on-my-hard-drive

Answer (score 0):

Try using the windows 7 install/repair disc. Click "repair your computer" and then open the command prompt. Try these 2 commands:

> bootrec /fixmbr

and

> bootrec /fixboot

more info: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/